# DAX opening balance calculation by day not correct on month and year

Tags: dax

The opening balance calculation does not work correctly. The error In the example below is that on a monthly and annual basis it should show zero and not six.

[image: End Balance and Opening Balance are separate tables]

The formula for the End Balance is:

```
End Balance :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Inventory Balance'[BalanceQuantity] );
    LASTNONBLANK (
        'Calendar'[CalendarDate];
        CALCULATE ( ( SUM ( 'Inventory Balance'[BalanceQuantity] ) ) )
    )
)
```

The formula for the Opening Balance is:

```
Opening Balance :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Inventory Opening Balance'[BalanceQuantity] );
    FIRSTNONBLANK (
        'Calendar'[CalendarDate];
        CALCULATE (
             ( SUM ( 'Inventory Opening Balance'[BalanceQuantity] ) )
        )
    )
)
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong :-(

Comment: it looks like you don't have any data on opening balance on 6/17/2020. it might be that no data is not the same as 0. and then the firstnonblank is 6 (on 6/18/2020)

Comment: You are right. Thank you